# Set hMailServer to redict all outbound smtp emails to one email account

Tags: email-server

For development purposes, I want to setup hMailServer such that:

1. **ALL** outbound email is redirected to another email address
   (i.e. it is not "sent" to the original email only one I choose), and
2. That email address/account is checkable by anyone with pop access

This is so we don't accidentally email customers while debugging issues on their dbs which contain a ton of email addresses.

I have looked at various settings e.g under protocol > SMTP and there is no direct settings I can see to do this so it must be a combination of settings?

I don't want to get it wrong as devs in the past have accidentally sent out hundreds of emails to customers.

Has anyone had experience setting hmailserver up in this fashion?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault!  Getting good answers requires the effort of [writing a good question](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681) and as it stands now yours is missing what you have already tried and where you are stuck. - Please edit and improve your question or run the risk of leaving your problem unresolved and/or having your question closed.

Comment: One is addressed in the [mirror address](https://www.hmailserver.com/documentation/latest/?page=reference_mirror) option, possibly with a [specific route](https://www.hmailserver.com/documentation/v5.2/?page=reference_route) for that domain and for instance a firewall that blocks all other outgoing traffic on port 25, or configure [relay server](https://www.hmailserver.com/documentation/latest/?page=howto_route_through_isp) that discards/refuses everything